# Loop over several dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have several data frames that I would like to be used in the same code, one after the other. In the code lines that I have written, I am using the variable "my_data" (which is basically a dataframe). Thus, I thought the easiest solution would be to assign each of my other dataframes to "my_data", one after the other, so that all the code that follows can be executed for each data frame in a loop without changing the code I already have.

The structure I have looks as follows:

```
#Datasets:
    my_data
    
    age_date
    gender_data
    income_data

   ## Code that uses "my_data" follows here" ##
```

How can I create a loop that first assigns "age_data" to "my_data" and executes the code where "my_data" was used as a variable. Then, after it reaches the end, restarts and assigns "gender_data" to the variable "my_data" and does the same until this has been done for all variables.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Look at the online documentation for `lapply` and related functions.

Comment: First step, put your data.frames into a list (it's preferable to do that when they are created). You can easily iterate over a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am attempting to answer based upon information provided:

```
datanames <- c("age_data","gender_data","income_data")

for (dname in datanames){
 my_data <- data.frame()
 my_data <- get(dname)
 # here you can write rest of the code
 rm(mydata)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. As ThomasIsCoding has used, get(dname) will work.

Comment: And `my_data <- data.frame()` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `get` within `for` loop

```
for (i in c(  "age_date", "gender_data","income_data")) {
  my_data <- get(i)
}
```